# Modify line if have new information, else nothing

Tags: git, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have a file with full of file routes and timestamps.

```
xxxx/view/css/animate.css/3.1.1/animate.min.css: 1494509091
xxxx/view/fonts/cinzel/fonts.css: 1494509091
xxxx/view/fonts/garamondcondot-book/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/gotham-narrow/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/gotham/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/greatvibes/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/indie-flower/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/katibeh/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/lobster-two/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/museo/fonts.css: 1494509092
xxxx/view/fonts/myriad-pro/fonts.css: 1494509092
```

The task is check every file last modified date with git log.
This is good, and working with this command:

```
sed -E 's|(.*): .*|echo \1: $(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" \1)|e' file.yml
```

This is very good and useful but i found a problem. As there are more then 500 file route, i had some file which i don't have any info in git log. And the problem is these files i can't get any timestamp information back from the sed command. 
The right way will be, if have new timestamp information from git log change, else do not nothing, so keep the old.

Ex.: If i don't have information in git log i received this error info:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'xxx/compiled/css/*FILENAME*': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Comment: `git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" \1 2> /dev/null` redirect standard error

Comment: Unfortunately not a good solution because where i don't have information in git log, i have whitespace:   catalog/view/theme/bellajuwelen/stylesheet/stylesheet.css: 1565000507 (good, so have information in git log)
catalog/view/theme/bikepro/stylesheet/animations.css:
catalog/view/theme/bikepro/stylesheet/fonts.css: (bad, i don't have information in git log but deleted the latest timestamp, whch is bad)
catalog/view/theme/bikepro/stylesheet/stylesheet.css:

Comment: how about `s|(.*): (.*)|echo \1: $(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" \1 2> /dev/null || echo \2)|e'`

Comment: Something went wrong, don't recognize s "button"

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'

Comment: you were initially using `|` as the sed separator, but the suggested new output also contains `|`. Escape these pipes, or use another separator.

Comment: oops, classic mistake :-/ can use `s#..#..#` here

Comment: No is running ut i have the same problem. Where i don't have new timestamp information, is still empty.   catalog/view/theme/csabits/stylesheet/stylesheet.css: 1565000507
catalog/view/theme/culina/stylesheet/custom.css:

Comment: hmm try `$(git log -1 --pretty="format:%ct" \1 |  grep -E ':.*[0-9]+$')` This will get only records ending with digits  after `:`

Comment: Unfortunately isn't good. I think i need an if statement, no? if git log finded new timestamp than change, else keep old timestamp from original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i solved with sed:

```
sed -i.bkp "s|$key: .*|$key: $new|g" file.yml
```